# Writing/Reading from text files in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am a student in computer science and for a project I need to be able to read from a text file in a way that each line is assigned to a space within an array. This should happen so that each line of text file is read in the order that it appears in the text file. I would also appreciate any methods of writing to a text file as well.

If this question is already explained, could you please direct me to the existing answer.

Things to note:

1) I am coding in a console application in VB.NET
2) I am relatively new at coding

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
Dim sFile As String = "D:\File.txt"
Dim aLines As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(sFile)

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(sFile, aLines)
```

Here's a sample from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines):

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTest.txt"
        Dim sw As StreamWriter

        ' This text is added only once to the file.
        If File.Exists(path) = False Then

            ' Create a file to write to.
            Dim createText() As String = {"Hello", "And", "Welcome"}
            File.WriteAllLines(path, createText)
        End If

        ' This text is always added, making the file longer over time
        ' if it is not deleted.
        Dim appendText As String = "This is extra text" + Environment.NewLine
        File.AppendAllText(path, appendText)

        ' Open the file to read from.
        Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
        Dim s As String
        For Each s In readText
            Console.WriteLine(s)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

> **Remarks**
>
> This method opens a file, reads each line of the file, then adds each line as an element of a string array. It then closes the file. A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return ('\r'), a line feed ('\n'), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed. The resulting string does not contain the terminating carriage return and/or line feed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    'Declare four variables
    Dim oReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(".\archive01.txt") 'This file has to exist in the aplication current directory.
    Dim oWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(".\archive02.txt") 'This file will be created by the software.
    Dim oArray() As String = {}
    Dim oString As String = Nothing

    'For reading from .\archive01.txt and to load in oArray().
    oString = oReader.ReadLine
    While Not oString Is Nothing
        If UBound(oArray) = -1 Then 'Ubound = Upper Bound, also exist LBound = Lower Bound.
            ReDim oArray(UBound(oArray) + 1)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve oArray(UBound(oArray) + 1)
        End If
        oArray(UBound(oArray)) = New String(oString)
        oString = oReader.ReadLine
    End While
    oReader.Close()

    'For writing from oArray() to .\archive02.txt.
    For i = 0 To oArray.Count - 1 Step 1
        oWriter.WriteLine(oArray(i))
    Next
    oWriter.Close()

End Sub

End Module
```

Hi, try with this code. It works well. I hope that this helps to you to learn how to do this kind of things. Thank you very much. And happy codding!. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this code. For it to work do i need to save a text file to the program beforehand or not?

Comment: @FZCube42, you have to create a file in the same directory of your executable and give to it the name: "archive01.txt". If you changed the name of this file then you don't forget to set the same name in the code to the software find the file. Then you can write lines in that file and save and close it. When you run the application arch02.txt will be created in the same directory that arch01.txt and your application. The file arch02.txt has the lines which were read from arch01.txt and loaded into the array() and then from this array they were written to arch02.txt. Thanks. Happy codding!. :)